# Extract just one value from json array result in vb6

Tags: arrays, json, vb6

The result of json that I received from the SMS sending panel by Rest API is as follows and display in textbox :

```
{
"status": "OK",
"code": "OK",
"message": "Ok",
"data": {
"messages": [
  {
    "number": "+9710001529",
    "message": "Hello World",
    "sender": "+97911308600",
    "time": "2022-07-12T20:12:14Z",
    "type": "normal"
  },
  {
    "number": "+9710001529",
    "message": "Just For Test",
    "sender": "+979051931024",
    "time": "2022-06-28T23:15:22Z",
    "type": "normal"
  },
  {
    "number": "+9710001529",
    "message": "Test",
    "sender": "+979565547989",
    "time": "2022-01-28T16:04:50Z",
    "type": "mobilepanel"
  },
    {
    "number": "+9710001529",
    "message": "Comment",
    "sender": "+979102900089",
    "time": "2018-06-16T22:23:23Z",
    "type": "normal"
  }
]
},
"meta": {
"total": 37,
"pages": 4,
"limit": 10,
"page": 0,
"prev": null,
"next": "http://0.0.0.0:80/v1/inbox?limit=10\u0026page=1"
}
}
```

Now, I need to fetch the first mobile number with the name "sender" and show it in textbox for searching in database. The result should look like this: `+97911308600`.

I downloaded VB-JSON, VB6 JSON Parser Class Library and try to get a specific field from JSON data structure. if json result was not array like this code works good:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"code": "OK",
"message": "Ok",
"data": {
"credit": 2655946.6574392905
}
}
```

my code :

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = json.parse(Text1.text)
Debug.Print p.Item("data").Item("credit")
```

My expected output :

```
 2655946.6574392905
```

The problem is when the Json result is a collection of arrays. How can I read first "sender" value as Mobile number just like value of "credit"?

Please guide me or post code. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

> `o.item("data").item("messages").item(1).item("number")`

Easy way to find out..

1. Put a breakpoint right after the `.Parse(...)` call and then stop your execution and proceed to the "Immediate Window".
2. Start debugging using the `TypeName(...)` method from VB6.

> `?TypeName(o)` => Dictionary
> `?TypeName(o.item("data"))` => Dictionary
> `?TypeName(o.item("data").item("messages"))` => Collection

So, this is how the parser renders the array of objects.  Instead of a Dictionary, it is a collection.  Collections can be indexed via numeric keys (base 1).

Thus,

> `?TypeName(o.item("data").item("messages").item(1))` => Dictionary

Now, we're  back to a Dictionary, so we're back on a JSON object as opposed to an array.  You could also have done `.Count` on the Collection if you needed to iterate.

And, then, finally, extract the field from the collection you wanted:

> `o.item("data").item("messages").item(1).item("number")` => +9710001529

And, you're there.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and comprehensive explanations . @User51

Answer (score 3):

Try using tiny [`mdJson.bas`](https://gist.github.com/wqweto/e92dce63a68cd3ff9ca91b053b9510c9) module from [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?871695-VB6-VBA-JSON-parsing-to-built-in-VBA-Collections-with-JSON-Path-support) thread instead of some bloated components and libraries.

It's a single file JSON parser implementation that uses nested `VBA.Collection`s to represent JSON objects and arrays and uses [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expressions to access nested data.

Your code would become this

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JsonParseObject(Text1.text)
Debug.Print JsonValue(p, "data/credit")
```

You can read the first sender like this

```
Debug.Print JsonValue(p, "messages/0/sender")
```

. . . or using JSON Path expressions like this

```
Debug.Print JsonValue(p, "$.messages[0].sender")
```